# Fuelphp cannot load pdf/pdf class

Tags: php, fuelphp

Im getting a 'C:/xampp/htdocs/gastro/fuel/packages/pdf/lib/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') error in my code can anybody tell me how to load the package https://github.com/TJS-Technology/fuel-pdf in my code the docs arent that clear on how to autoload the pdf class please help me

Comment: Have you done all that is written here - https://github.com/TJS-Technology/fuel-pdf#adding-libraries ? Also show your full error.

Comment: what did he mean by downloading the Download the PHP5 PDF library I dont seem to see download link in the docs.

Comment: This — http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.installation.php

Comment: I still dont understan :(

Comment: There is a [PECL extension called `pdflib`](https://pecl.php.net/package/pdflib). You have to install it in order to work with PDF.

Comment: here is my error http://imgur.com/gycBNtm

Comment: Looks like you have another `\Pdf\Pdf` class. Can you try `$pdf = new \Pdf\Pdf;` instead of line with `forge`? Just to be sure.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I use  $pdf = new  \Pdf\Pdf::forge('dompdf')->init();

Comment: No, use exactly my line `$pdf = new \Pdf\Pdf;` instead of the whole your line, replace it. Then show error you'll get.

Comment: thanks but for your suggestion I tried my own way and figured it out the solution is to autoload the class in C:\xampp\htdocs\gastro\fuel\core\bootstrap.php and add this line of faking code   'Pdf\\Pdf'  => PKGPATH . 'pdf/classes/pdf.php', and works like magic.